# Possible number of arrangement.

Tags: permutations, self-learning

**Question:**

How many cars are there with number GJ-X-AB-abcd. GJ and A are constant.X is digit between 1 to 9, B is english alphabet and abcd is 4 digit number.(a can be zero)

**My Efforts:**

It is but natural car's number plate have repetition.

So, X can be arranged in 9 different ways.

AB can be arranged in 26 different ways.

abcd can be arranged in $10\times10\times10\times10=10000$ different ways.

So the total number of arrangement is $2340000$. But answer given is $2339766$, which is a little less than the expected.

Comment: $2339766 = 26 \cdot 11 \cdot 101 \cdot 9^2$... There has to be something missing here.

Comment: From your way to do it, you should get 2340000 --- you missed a factor of 10.

Comment: I'm guessing they don't count 0000 as a 4-digit number.

Comment: Yes they dont , thats why I think he mentions that only a can be zero.

Comment: Shouldnt it be 10 x 9 x 9 x 9  for abcd???

Comment: @Tharindu a can be zero means number with thousandth place 0 is also considered as 4 digit number.

Comment: Oh ok , got it....

Comment: @GerryMyerson You are right, abcd as 0000 can come in 26* 9=234 different ways. So if we subtract 2340000-234 we will get 2339766. Please post it as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Now that you understand it, you can post it as an answer yourself, and then accept it (although the software may make you wait a while).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

abcd can be arranged in $10 \times 10 \times 10 \times 10=10000$ different ways, but it also contain 0000, which need to be excluded from total arrangement.

0000 can come $26 \times 9= 234$ times in arrangement.

Therefore, $234$ is to be subtracted from total possible arrangement.

$2340000-234=23393766$

Thank you Gerry Myerson for your help.